# Extended EditText class wont instantiate

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to extend the EditText class but I can't seem to get it to work. I've created this class in my public class MainActivity extends Activity as a sub class:

```
public class EditText2 extends EditText
{

    public EditText2(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public EditText2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public EditText2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }       
}
```

and tried hand coding and using the Graphical Layout tab in Eclipse to edit the activity_main.xml to add the new class as such:

```
<first.words.firstwords.MainActivity.EditText2
    android:id="@+id/user_input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="EditText2" >

    <requestFocus />
</first.words.firstwords.MainActivity.EditText2>
```

But I get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.getDefaultProperties(RenderSessionImpl.java:1476)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.getDefaultProperties(BridgeRenderSession.java:68)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.ViewHierarchy.getDefaultProperties(ViewHierarchy.java:710)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getStringValue(XmlProperty.java:209)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getValue(XmlProperty.java:221)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.getText(XmlPropertyEditor.java:116)
>       at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlPropertyEditor.paint(XmlPropertyEditor.java:131)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawProperty(PropertyTable.java:1309)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawContent(PropertyTable.java:1151)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.handlePaint(PropertyTable.java:1094)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.access$200(PropertyTable.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable$3.handleEvent(PropertyTable.java:187)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1300)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1285)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_expose_event(Control.java:2992)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_expose_event(Composite.java:709)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.gtk_expose_event(Canvas.java:167)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1769)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5116)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4377)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:8317)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1193)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gdk_window_process_all_updates(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gdk_window_process_all_updates(OS.java:5571)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.update(Display.java:4330)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredLayouts(Display.java:3588)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3173)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

from the activity_main.xml and ClassNotFoundException when I run the application.
I've googled around and looked at [Extending a EditText in Android. What do I do wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648924/extending-a-edittext-in-android-what-do-i-do-wrong) and [What's the right way to extend EditText to give it additional “default” functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518573/whats-the-right-way-to-extend-edittext-to-give-it-additional-default-function) among others to no avail.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong as I've spent hours looking myself and can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you `EditText2` is an inner class. You should reference it as follows () using `$`):

```
<view class="first.words.firstwords.MainActivity$EditText2"
...
...
```

Alternatively, move this to a new class file (eg: `EditText2.java`).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098318/error-referencing-an-inner-class-view-in-layout-main-xml) are some more suggestions for you to try.

Comment: Ah, ok, I get it. I knew I must have been forgeting something.
Interesting point: using EditText insted of View for the xml tag will still fail. Thanks Amulya.